# Seeking solution to using PostgreSQL/PostGIS views in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, postgis-2.0, database

We are currently trying to 'clean up' our geodatabase. For example: we have 30 datasets of districts, each of a different year (1986-2016). To make it more visible, we want to combine them all into 1 dataset where we use a view for the most recent one. There are some issues when we create a view. First, we cannot set a primary key (we use PostgreSQL together with PostGIS) in a view. A user must specify a primary key each time he drags the view into ArcMap. Second, for some reason, when creating a view, ArcGIS recognizes 2 datasets: a table and a query layer (see image). I have no idea why. In PgAdmin it looks like one tableview. Catalog also crashes when trying to open the table version.

Is there a way to set and save a primary key in ArcGIS, since it cannot be done using PostgreSQL? And what causes ArcGIS to show two datasets of the same view, a table and a query layer? If not, are there any alternatives to these problems?

[image]

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE gemeentegrenzen
(
  objectid serial NOT NULL,
  gem_nr integer,
  gem_naam character varying(30),
  jaar smallint,
  prov_code character varying(10),
  prov_naam character varying(28),
  cbs_code character varying(6),
  shape geometry,
  CONSTRAINT gemeentegrenzen_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_shape CHECK (st_srid(shape) = 28992)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE gemeentegrenzen
  OWNER TO geo;

-- Index: sidx_54890_8

-- DROP INDEX sidx_54890_8;

CREATE INDEX sidx_54890_8
  ON gemeentegrenzen
  USING gist
  (shape);
```

My view definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gemeenten_actueel AS 
 SELECT gemeentegrenzen.objectid,
    gemeentegrenzen.gem_nr,
    gemeentegrenzen.gem_naam,
    gemeentegrenzen.jaar,
    gemeentegrenzen.prov_code,
    gemeentegrenzen.prov_naam,
    gemeentegrenzen.cbs_code,
    st_transform(gemeentegrenzen.shape, 28992)::geometry(Geometry,28992) AS shape
   FROM gemeentegrenzen
  WHERE gemeentegrenzen.jaar = 2016;

ALTER TABLE gemeenten_actueel
  OWNER TO geo;
```

Both are stored in a PostgreSQL 9.4 database with postgis 2.0. ArcGIS is version 10.3.

Comment: If you don't include the view SQL and column types, it's unlike you will get a useful answer. The most likely cause is use of unsupported column types. Please **edit the question**  to contain table and view definitions as well as versions of all software to three digits (e.g., "10.4.1",...) You also have a laundry-list of issues, whic violates the "One question per Question" policy.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for the feedback. I do have 2 issues, but both are related to the same single question, and that's using views of PostgrSQL in ArcGIS.

Comment: Two questions is two Questions. The environment is related but the *answers* are not. Since the possiblilty of end-around of rowid column selection has already been answered (not possible), you'll need to focus on the real issue.

Comment: Why are you using ST_Transform when the SRID does not change?  The "Put all the features in one table and select out what I need" approach has been proven to be very inefficient (*slow*) time and time again. If you must follow this pattern, I recommend a *materialized view*, so a spatial index can be used.

Comment: I had to use this, because otherwise the view gets no record in the geometry_columns view and is therefore not visible in ArcGIS (http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column). Since Postgis 2.0 the geometry_columns is a view instead of a table, where I could just insert the record into the table. If it is proven slow, does that mean you recommend having separate tables for all district-years as best solution in the end?

Comment: There was no such requirement at 10.3.1, 10.4, or 10.4.1, and doing so at 10.3 makes no sense. The properties are obtained from the query itself.

Comment: You've got some platform issues: The appropriate PostGIS for PG 9.4 is 2.2.  PG 9.4 support wasn't introduced until ArcGIS 10.4. In addition, 10.4.x added read/write capability to PostgreSQL without enterprise geodatabase enablement.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to know what version of everything you are using, and how the view was created but, I think you have a bit of a permissions issue going on. If you see data twice in ArcMap or ArcCatalog then your schema permissions are somehow not right. Most commonly folks forget to grant "usage" or " all" on the schema.

A view created in a db is not registered with the gdb, which is why in ArcMap you are asked to indicate the column to be used as a primary key, because that information is usually read from the metadata.

Without any further information, I would assume that ArcMap is crashing on you because either of the view definition ( does the query used to create the view successfully resolve in PostGIS?) or the assumed priv problem.

Comment: I have created my district table (gemeentegrenzen) by importing a feature into my database using ArcCatalog. From there I created a view (see OP how I created my view using SQL). My schema is default, although I did grant all to the schema, without difference.

I also created the view in ArcCatalog, instead of in PostgreSQL itself, but also with no positive result.

Comment: so, for clarification purposes....

Comment: 1. use AC to import or c/p a feature class

Comment: a. were you logged in as a user with had a corresponding schema created in pg? For example: gis login user, with a schema called gis, with 'all' or 'usage' granted to the schema

Comment: 2 create the view, either in pg with sql, or as a right click on the connection file or using a gp tool?

Comment: 3. AC displays it but AM crashe

Comment: Is this a correct representation of your workflow?

Comment: Almost. Point 3 is different. AM and AC crashes when I click on the table of the view. Both work if I want to look at the actual feature-file. It somehow creates 2 datasets when making a view (see image). The table one crashes in both AM and AC.

Comment: PS: i connect directly to the database, no sde installed